# Is there a standard way of declaring dependency versions as variables in Gradle that can then be referenced in the dependencies block?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I am still fairly new to Gradle so wanted to check what is the recommended gradle equivalent for declaring all dependency versions in a singular place much like Maven’s `properties` tag

Example `pom.xml` -

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.6</lombok.version>
    <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
    ...
</properties>

...

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

So far I have come across the following ways to accomplish the same in Gradle

1. Declaring them as part of the `ext` block in the `buildscript` block in `build.gradle` .

   Example build.gradle -

   ```
   buildscript {
       ext {
           LOMBOK_VERSION = '1.18.6'
           JUNIT_VERSION = '5.5.2'
           MOCKITO_VERSION = '3.1.0'
           SPRING_BOOT_VERSION = '2.2.4.RELEASE'
           SWAGGER_VERSION = '2.9.2'
       }

   }
   ...
   dependencies {
      compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$LOMBOK_VERSION"
       implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$SPRING_BOOT_VERSION"
       implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:$SWAGGER_VERSION"
       implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:$SWAGGER_VERSION"
       testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$SPRING_BOOT_VERSION"
     testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$JUNIT_VERSION"
     testIimplementation "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:$MOCKITO_VERSION"
     runtimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$JUNIT_VERSION"
   }
   ```
2. Declaring them as part of the `ext` block in the root level

   ```
   ext {
       LOMBOK_VERSION = '1.18.6'
       JUNIT_VERSION = '5.5.2'
       MOCKITO_VERSION = '3.1.0'
       SPRING_BOOT_VERSION = '2.2.4.RELEASE'
       SWAGGER_VERSION = '2.9.2'
   }

   ...
   dependencies {
      compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$LOMBOK_VERSION"
       implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$SPRING_BOOT_VERSION"
       implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:$SWAGGER_VERSION"
       implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:$SWAGGER_VERSION"
       testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$SPRING_BOOT_VERSION"
     testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$JUNIT_VERSION"
     testIimplementation "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:$MOCKITO_VERSION"
     runtimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$JUNIT_VERSION"
   }
   ```
3. Declaring them as local variables in the `dependencies` block itself using `def`

   ```
   ...

   dependencies {
      def LOMBOK_VERSION = '1.18.6'
      def JUNIT_VERSION = '5.5.2'
      def MOCKITO_VERSION = '3.1.0'
      def SPRING_BOOT_VERSION = '2.2.4.RELEASE'
      def SWAGGER_VERSION = '2.9.2'

      compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$LOMBOK_VERSION" 
      implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:$SPRING_BOOT_VERSION" 
      implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:$SWAGGER_VERSION"      
      implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:$SWAGGER_VERSION" 
      testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$SPRING_BOOT_VERSION" 
      testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$JUNIT_VERSION" 
      testIimplementation "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:$MOCKITO_VERSION" 
      runtimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$JUNIT_VERSION" 
   }
   ```
4. Declaring them in the `gradle.properties` file

   ```
   org.gradle.caching=true
   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
   org.gradle.parallel=true
   # Dependency versions
   lombokVersion=1.18.12 
   junitVersion=5.5.2 
   mockitoVersion=3.1.0 
   springBootVersion=2.2.4.RELEASE 
   swaggerVersion=2.9.2
   ```

I am not sure which one is **preferred** and which one should be **avoided** if any ?

Answer (score 1):

The choice is subjective, and enforcement is down to personal coding style or code formatting rules.

Personally -
`version` numbers are 'Code' - they are needed in `dependencies` and/or `plugins`

`gradle.properties` is not the place - because its purpose is not code itself
options 2,3 (`ext`, within `dependencies`) are not visible in `plugins`

`buildscript` block supports global declaration but is not much used with new `plugins` style

I have hard-coded version numbers in `plugins` and `ext` declared in the dependencies.